# Uploading HFiles in Hbase fails because of method not found error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

I am trying to upload Hfiles to Hbase using bulkload. While doing so I am encountering method not found error . Giving the logs and command below.

Command

```
     hadoop jar /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-server-0.98.11-hadoop2.jar completebulkload /output NBAFinal2010
```

where output is the Hfiles output folder and NBAFinal2010 is table in Hbase.

logs :-

```
    15/05/05 13:20:12 ERROR mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Unexpected execution exception during bulk load
  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerFactory.instantiate(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/RpcRetryingCallerFactory;
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
```

Can anyone help me out here. Unable to get a possible solution after lot of searching.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles hdfs://<ip_address>:9000/output NBAFinal2010
```